# MvvmCross Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross, android-lifecycle, xiaomi

I am trying to create a mobile application using MvvmCross v.4.4.0.
Application works correct. But if collapse application and lock the phone, and then unlock and press "Overview" android button application crash (only on the Xiaomi phone).
I think android kills activity and then unsuccessfully trying to recreate it.

Could you, please explain me, what I do wrong? How to fix it?

Stacktrace:

```
Android.Runtime.RaiseThrowableEventArgs MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type Test.Core.ViewModels.MainMenuViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Problem creating viewModel of type MainMenuViewModel ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to construct MainMenuViewModel ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Java.Lang.LinkageError: no static method "Landroid/text/Html;.fromHtml(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/text/Spanned;" at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
[0x0000c] in <89dd20b27a0b473a848558c84f1f086a>:0 at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.GetStaticMethodID (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, System.String name, System.String signature)
[0x00068] in :0 at Java.Interop.JniType.GetStaticMethod (System.String name, System.String signature)
[0x0000d] in :0 at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.GetMethodInfo (System.String encodedMember)
[0x0003c] in :0 at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
[0x00001] in :0 at Android.Text.Html.FromHtml (System.String source, Android.Text.FromHtmlOptions flags)
[0x0003b] in :0 at Test.Droid.Providers.DialogProvider.ShowSnackbar () [0x00017] in <0fa1f44ee2f748fe816e790571c2153b>:0 at Test.Core.ViewModels.BaseViewModel..ctor ()
[0x0006d] in :0 at Test.Core.ViewModels.MainMenuViewModel..ctor (Test.Core.Managers.IExceptionManager exceptionManager)
[0x0000b] in :0 at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters)
[0x00002] in <89dd20b27a0b473a848558c84f1f086a>:0 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters)
[0x0001c] in <89dd20b27a0b473a848558c84f1f086a>:0 at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
[0x00089] in <89dd20b27a0b473a848558c84f1f086a>:0 at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
[0x00000] in <89dd20b27a0b473a848558c84f1f086a>:0 at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters)
[0x00000] in <89dd20b27a0b473a848558c84f1f086a>:0 at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type)
[0x0003a] in <4ddde23419c5494288c799fcdbb0f189>:0 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type)
[0x0005b] in <4ddde23419c5494288c799fcdbb0f189>:0 at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t)
[0x00005] in <4ddde23419c5494288c799fcdbb0f189>:0 at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState)
[0x00000] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState)
[0x00027] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator)
[0x00015] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator)
[0x00046] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState)
[0x00020] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.ViewModelFromRequest (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest viewModelRequest, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState)
[0x00005] in :0 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.CreateViewModelFromIntent (Android.Content.Intent intent, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState)
[0x00027] in :0 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.Load (Android.Content.Intent intent, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState, System.Type viewModelTypeHint)
[0x00089] in :0 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView androidView, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState)
[0x0006a] in :0 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__1 ()
[0x0000a] in :0 at MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Core.Views.IMvxView view, System.Func`1[TResult] viewModelLoader)
[0x00012] in <69bce0378e8e413982d3b552d7e387a8>:0 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView androidView, Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
[0x00062] in :0 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled (System.Object sender, MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1[T] eventArgs)
[0x0000c] in :0 at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1[Android.OS.Bundle]]:invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1) at MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise[T] (System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] eventHandler, System.Object sender, T value)
[0x0000b] in <4ddde23419c5494288c799fcdbb0f189>:0 at MvvmCross.Platform.Droid.Views.MvxEventSourceActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
[0x00014] in <4230cf00b647458f9b3e211590e6cc9d>:0 at Test.Droid.Views.BaseView`1[TViewModel].OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
[0x00000] in <0fa1f44ee2f748fe816e790571c2153b>:0 at Test.Droid.Views.MainMenuView.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
[0x00000] in <0fa1f44ee2f748fe816e790571c2153b>:0 at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState)
[0x00011] in :0 at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:e6d6ef29-3746-4c8e-b037-c64f6dfe49f0 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a linking issue. You have some kind of DialogProvider, which uses the `Android.Text.Html.FromHtml` method, which seems to be stripped out.

You can add expressions to `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` to prevent the linker from removing code or you can add `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` attribute on your `DialogProvider` class.

Comment: Thank you very mutch for answer. What I have to add to the `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` class?
Could you, please provide me a code? Thank you.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/linking